# sshfs mount - files/folder are created as root, disregarding uid/gid options

Tags: files, sshfs, ownership

**Local**: OpenSUSE, mount point `/home/gruz/debian`

**Remote**: Debian (VirtualBox) `192.168.0.100`, mount point `/var/www/a`

I want to mount folder in `192.168.0.100:/var/www/a` to my local machine so when I create a file/folder at the mounted folder at my local machine it's created with `www-data:www-data` at the server (which is 33:33 at Debian). 
But it's created with `root:root` owner (0:0).

At my local OpenSUSE I make sure I have correct owner:

```
sudo chown 33:33 /home/gruz/debian
```

Next I mount it like this:

```
sudo sshfs -o uid=33,gid=33,allow_other root@192.168.0.100:/var/www/a /home/gruz/debian
```

If I `mkdir` a folder at the mount, it's created with 33:33:

```
gruz@linux-k9eu:~/debian> ls -lan
total 16
drwxr-xr-x  1   33  33 4096 Apr 28 16:13 .
drwxr-xr-x 41 1000 100 4096 Apr 28 16:08 ..
drwxr-xr-x  1   33  33 4096 Apr 28 16:10 aa
drwxr-xr-x  1   33  33 4096 Apr 28 16:13 bb
```

But at the server I see 0:0:

```
root@debian:/var/www/a# ls -lan
total 16
drwxr-xr-x 4 33 33 4096 Apr 28 09:13 .
drwxr-xr-x 6  0  0 4096 Apr 28 09:09 ..
drwxr-xr-x 2  0  0 4096 Apr 28 09:10 aa
drwxr-xr-x 2  0  0 4096 Apr 28 09:13 bb
```

And what is strange when I run `mount -v` at my local machine, I can see

```
root@192.168.0.100:/var/www/a on /home/gruz/debian type fuse.sshfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,allow_other)
```

So sshfs seems to ignore `uid=33,gid=33,`

Please, give advice.

Answer (score 2):

On the remote machine the files are created with the user you use to login. The output of `mount -v` shows that you login as root. Use `sshfs www-data@192.168.0.100:/var/www/a /home/gruz/debian` to mount the remote directory.

The `-o` flag changes the uid/gid of the remote files on the local machine. You could run the `sshfs` command as the other user if you would want him to own the mountpoint. There is no need for that if you want to work with the files with the user `gruz`.

Comment: I cannot use `www-data@192.168.0.100` because www-data at debian is very tricky to make loginable. And insecure. 

In other words I want to work with files as `gruz`, I can login as `root` and I want the new files to be saved as `www-data`. Is this possible at all? I need to edit remote files from my localhost (as from a refular folder to be able to use my IDE) and not care of chown at the server each time I create something.

Comment: I don't think `root` is better, you should use `gruz`: https://serverfault.com/questions/158392/how-do-i-sudo-over-sshfs

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I'm so tired with the problem, that I have enabled www-data login. I have no passion to try the link now. But thanks for it, I'll try it later.